# Cassandra in cluster - 1000 query in 1s [1000ms]

Tags: javascript, node.js, cassandra

I would like to query the same database (with script) 1000 times in 1s.

So I did some simulation test with nodejs for loop. I sent out 50 query request but the response came back very slow in around 400 ms

I am using simply loop - amount of query

setInterval - amount of 1k-1s requests

My question: is it possible to do 1000 queries in 1s, even force it somehow?
I would also like to test how the database works on more queries (10000, 100000). The logic thing would be that database returns busy state.

```
funcname(){
.
 for(var i=0;i<50; i++) {
.
.
   client[ randomHostId ].execute(query, 
     [ ids[ Math.floor(Math.random() *   1000) ] ], 
     { prepare: true },function (err, result) {...})
.
.
}
const time = setInterval(funcname, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you provided, the code is doing what is commonly known as "fire and forget": starting a bunch of operations and don't await for the result to launch new ones.

Usually you need to control the amount of operation that occur in parallel. You can achieve it by using popular control flow libraries such as [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html) or [async utilities](https://github.com/caolan/async).

There's also an example in the repository on how to insert large number of rows in a table limiting the amount of parallel requests: https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/master/examples/concurrent-executions/execute-in-loop.js

There's also a concurrent utilities API built-in the driver that can help you: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/nodejs-driver/4.1/features/concurrent-api/

```
const query = 'INSERT INTO table1 (id, value) VALUES (?, ?)';
const parameters = [[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c'], ]; // ...
const result = await executeConcurrent(client, query, parameters);
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54810019/208683